# CodeBuild: How to generate secondary artifacts

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-codebuild

I'm currently designing a BuildSpec via CDK for my pipeline, and I can't seem to get the `SecondaryArtifacts` property right.
Here is the [relevant documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-spec-ref.html#build-spec.artifacts.secondary-artifacts) concerning `SecondaryArtifacts`, and here's what I tried so far:

```
const buildSpecJSON = {
      version: "0.2",
      phases: {
        install: {
          "runtime-versions": {
            nodejs: "14.x",
          },
          commands: ["npm install -g aws-cdk"],
        },
        build: {
          commands: [
            "npm ci && npm run prepare-deploy && npm run build && cd cdk",
            "cdk synth CommonInfrastructureStack AssetDeploymentStack BusinessAssetAPIStack",
          ],
        },
      },
      reports: {
        [testReports.reportGroupArn]: {
          files: ["unit_tests_coverage.xml"],
          "file-format": "JUNITXML",
          "base-directory": "coverage/",
        },
        [coverageReports.reportGroupArn]: {
          files: ["cobertura-coverage.xml"],
          "file-format": "COBERTURAXML",
          "base-directory": "coverage/",
        },
      },
      artifacts: {
        "base-directory": "cdk/cdk.out/",
        files: [
          "CommonInfrastructureStack.template.json",
          "AssetDeploymentStack.template.json",
          "BusinessAssetAPIStack.template.json",
        ],
        "secondary-artifacts": {
          dist: {
            files: ["*"],
            name: "dist",
            "base-directory": "dist/",
          },
        },
      },
    }
```

The problem is it's not generating any secondary-artifacts. There is no error message as well, so I do not know if the problem is that the `dist` folder is empty, even though it most likely isn't, or if the YAML isn't correct.

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was that I was too focused on the `buildspec` and not the `CodeBuildAction` itself.
For the future people who'll come thru this problem, you have to understand that you **cannot** define both an `Artifact` and `SecondaryArtifacts` at the same time.

The correct `buildspec` provided to the `BuildSpec.fromObject(buildSpecJSON)` method is the following:

```js
const lambdaBuildOutput = new Artifact("DistArtifact")
const cdkBuildOutput = new Artifact("CdkBuildOutput")
const lambdaLayer = new Artifact("LayerArtifact")
const buildSpecJSON = {
      version: "0.2",
      ...
      artifacts: {
        files: ["**/*"],
        "secondary-artifacts": {
          CdkBuildOutput: {
            "base-directory": "cdk/cdk.out/",
            files: [
              "CommonInfrastructureStack.template.json",
              "AssetDeploymentStack.template.json",
              "BusinessAssetAPIStack.template.json",
            ],
            name: "CdkBuildOutput",
          },
          DistArtifact: {
            files: ["*"],
            name: "DistArtifact",
            "base-directory": "dist/",
          },
          LayerArtifact: {
            files: ["**/*"],
            name: "LayerArtifact",
            "base-directory": "cdk/lambda-layer/nodejs/",
          },
        },
      },
    }
```

And then, provide the extra outputs thru the `outputs` prop on `CodeBuildAction`

```js
const buildAction = new CodeBuildAction({
      actionName: "CDK-Build",
      project: cdkBuild,
      input: sourceArtifact,
      outputs: [cdkBuildOutput, lambdaBuildOutput, lambdaLayer],
    })
```

This was the note provided thru the CDK documentation that pushed me in the right way:

> Note: if you specify more than one output Artifact here, you cannot use the primary 'artifacts' section of the buildspec; you have to use the 'secondary-artifacts' section instead. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/sample-multi-in-out.html for details.

I hope this will help anyone that comes this way.
Thanks again to @fedonev for their answer that also helped me.

Answer (score 3):

Artifacts appear twice in the [codebuild.Project constructor props](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_codebuild.Project.html). You have added the secondary artifact to the `buildspec`, but (I am guessing) not the Project's `secondaryArtifacts: IArtifacts[]` property:

> [CodeBuild Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/sample-multi-in-out.html): The `secondaryArtifacts` attribute contains a list of artifact definitions. These artifacts use the `secondary-artifacts` block of the buildspec file that is nested inside the `artifacts` block.

Add a `secondaryArtifacts` prop.  Reference its `Artifact` `identifier` value (`DistArtifact` in the example below) in the `buildspec`.  The CDK syntax looks like this:

```js
new codebuild.Project(this, 'SecondaryArtifactProject', {
  // ... code
  artifacts: codebuild.Artifacts.s3({
    bucket,
    packageZip: false,
    includeBuildId: false,
    // name: '/',  <-- can also set the S3 name here.  This attribute takes precedence over the buildspec `name`
  }),
  secondaryArtifacts: [
    codebuild.Artifacts.s3({
      bucket,
      includeBuildId: false,
      packageZip: false,
      identifier: 'DistArtifact', // arbitrary label - refer to this in buildspec
    }),
  ],
  buildSpec: codebuild.BuildSpec.fromObject({
    // ... code
    artifacts: {
      'base-directory': 'cdk/cdk.out/', // path in source
      files: [ "files..." ],
      name: 'cdk.out', // s3 output key; optional, used if artifact.name is undefined
      'secondary-artifacts': {
        DistArtifact: { // use the identifier you defined above in `secondaryArtifacts`
          'base-directory': 'dist/',
          files: ['**/*'],
          name: 'dist'
        },
      },
    },
  }),
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Even though we didn't use the same methods or APIs, your contribution nudged me in the right direction!
I'll post my answer right away!